# Fetch and paginate records more than 200000 with only one database interaction in php mysql

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I have to fetch more than 2,00,000 records at once and use the paging of 100 or 1000 records per page without interacting to database again and again .

Like we can have a virtual cache or hidden record-set from where my paging will show records.I heard that it is possible but did not find the proper solution.

Please suggest me the if anyone have solution for my requirement , i am using PHP and mysql.

Thanks,

Comment: Store all the records in a cookie, then paginate the contents of the cookie.

Comment: You can store the results in the user session, but if you'll end up using large amounts of memory if you store many search results. Why can't you get from the db several times?

Comment: To balance speed and memory, you should consider getting max 1000 records and paginate from cache etc. after 1000 records browsed, you can get another 1000 in cache, but at any moment max 1000 records or so.

Comment: You mention you're using PHP.  That probably means you're serving up 100 or 1000 records at a time to some user's web page upon request from the user.  Given that HTTP is a stateless protocol, how can you guarantee the rest of your records will still be in RAM when the user wants the next page?  Can you explain what you're trying to do -- from a user point of view?

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 choices here:
Make one DB transaction and overload the clients DOM or do multiple DB calls.

My suggestion is to take the middle path, select in 10 000 's, display data and then when they wish to paginate from beyond that you ajax more results in.